# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select GROUP_CONCAT(sum(documents.grand_total) SEPARATOR ",") as total

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, laravel-query-builder, group-concat

I'm getting this error I want to sum the grand total for every month against every contact group by every month but when I'm running the query it says this error **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select GROUP_CONCAT(sum(documents.grand_total) SEPARATOR ",") as total**

when do ***GROUP_CONCAT(documents.grand_total) as total*** I get all the grand total but sum against every contact coma separated here is my laravel query

```
$Months =  DB::table('documents')
            ->join('contacts', 'documents.contact_id', '=', 'contacts.id')
            ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(sum(documents.grand_total) SEPARATOR ",") as total 
            ,DATE_FORMAT(documents.due_date,"%M") as month ,
             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT contacts.name SEPARATOR ",") as names')
            ->where(
                [
                    ['documents.company_id', '=', session('current_company')],
                    ['documents.document_type', '=', 1],
                    ['documents.status', '=', 2],
                ]
            )
            ->whereMonth('documents.created_at', '=', now())
            ->orWhereMonth('documents.created_at', '=', now()->subMonths(1))
            ->orWhereMonth('documents.created_at', '=', now()->subMonths(2))
            ->orWhereMonth('documents.created_at', '=', now()->subMonths(3))
            ->orWhereMonth('documents.created_at', '=', now()->subMonths(4))
            ->orWhereMonth('documents.created_at', '>', now())
            ->orWhereMonth('documents.created_at', '<', now()->subMonths(4))
            ->groupByRaw('DATE_FORMAT(documents.due_date,"%M")')
            ->orderBy('documents.due_date')
            ->get();
```

the result im getting right now is all documents.grand_total by using only **group_concat(`documents`.`grand_total`)** is this

```
   Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1570 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#1560 ▼
      +"total": "53.51,53.51,53.51,53.51,53.51,53.51,53.51"
      +"month": "March"
      +"names": "Darrel Little"
    }
    1 => {#1565 ▼
      +"total": "584.78,106.56,40.36,820.46,49.17,96.56,90.53,51.36,44.87,158.76,673.24,203.26,51.36"
      +"month": "September"
      +"names": "Dane Cruickshank IV,Darrel Little,Dr. Enola Marks,Electa Harris"
    }
    2 => {#1561 ▼
      +"total": "53.51,108.58,108.58,108.58,353.35"
      +"month": "October"
      +"names": "Dane Cruickshank IV,Darrel Little,Dr. Wanda Hyatt MD"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I want coma separated  grand_total sum for each contact, please help me I'm stuck on this form last two days thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `GROUP_CONCAT(SUM(...))` with just SUM?

Comment: when I do this it gives an error  which is mentioned above 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select group_concat(sum(documents.grand_total))

Answer (score 1):

GROUP_CONCAT(SUM()) always shows **#1111 - Invalid use of group function** error..
So instead of adding sum, You can use this example to learn a way to do that,

```
 SELECT customer_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(product_id,':',quantity_sum SEPARATOR ' ; ' ) 
FROM 
(SELECT customer_id,product_id,sum(quantity) as quantity_sum 
from plus2_sale group by customer_id,product_id) a
 group by customer_id
```

So In your case,Your query should be like below. And I think this would work

```
'select * , GROUP_CONCAT(sum_grand_total SEPARATOR ",") as total  from (select * ,sum(grand_total) as sum_grand_total from document) as document_details ...'
```

You can use [this tutorial](https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/group_concat.php) to learn more about group_concat